# Is there any VHDL 93 or 2002 code that is incompatible with VHDL 2008?

Tags: vhdl, simulation, synthesizer

Is there any VHDL 93 or 2002 code that is incompatible with VHDL 2008?

In other words, if I have a bunch of files made for older vhdl standards, will a 2008 simulation/compilation work just fine?

Phrased differently, is there ANY reason NOT to use the a simulator/compiler in vhdl 2008 mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the whole, VHDL 2008 reuses existing reserved words to achieve new things (without warping the syntax, they are still "good words to use" in the context).

Leafing through my copy of "[VHDL-2008 - just the new stuff](http://www.ashenden.com.au/new-stuff/)" some potential collisions with existing code that I noticed are:

- Predefined `maximum` and `minimum` functions - they may collide with ones you have defined, although I imagine would function the same :)
- There is now the functionality for `force` and `release` on signals to override their values from testbenches.  Those words may collide with your code
- New functions `to_string`, `to_ostring` and `to_hstring` to convert types to a natural, octal or hexdecimal string.  Also a `justify` function.
- New reading and writing functions: `read`, `write`, `oread`, `owrite`, `hread`, `hwrite`. Also, `bread` and `bwrite` and `sread` and `swrite`.  And a `flush` procedure.  The `textio` library gains a `tee` function.
- The `numeric_*` packages gain `find_leftmost` and `find_rightmost` functions.
- The type `integer_vector` is pre-defined, but again probably means the same as any type you'd already created.  Also `boolean_vector`, `real_vector`, `time_vector`
- A new environment package `env` which contains `stop` and `finish` procedures and a `resolution_limit` function.

---

The list of new reserved words is given in section 9.22:
`context`
`default`
`force`
`parameter`
`release`

And these PSL reserved words are also reserved in VHDL2008:
`assert`
`assume`
`assume_guarantee`
`civer`
`fairness`
`property`
`restrict`
`restrict_property`
`sequence`
`strong`
`vmode`
`vprop`
`vunit`

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Martin's list, the VHDL-93 style of shared variables are deprecated, and may have to be turned into variables of VHDL-2002/2008 protected types.